# Where can I paste my website folder in Ubuntu XAMPP for it to access local host server?

Tags: xampp

Where can I paste my website folder  in Ubuntu localhost, the files I coded in windows where I used wamp server and store them in www folder

Answer (score 0):

Put your folder in /opt/lampp/htdocs/

Comment: I'm I supposed to change anything in my php code so that it can submit to my database??

Answer (score 0):

First, you should have access to your account, flow instruction:
Change username with yours.

```sh
sudo chown username:username /opt/lampp/htdocs
sudo chmod 777 /opt/lampp/htdocs
```

Then, you can copy your files to:

> /opt/lampp/htdocs/